# MySQL: Оператор IF ... THEN не корректно срабатывает в хранимой функции

Tags: mysql, if

Пишу функцию для  MySql. В теле функции есть строки

```
SELECT `id`, `val` INTO @CACHEID, @OLDVAL FROM `shop_ch_cache`
WHERE `prodid` = PRODID AND `nameid` = NAMEID LIMIT 1;

IF @CACHEID THEN
INSERT INTO `_db_log`(`log`) VALUES(CONCAT('id isset ', @CACHEID));
RETURN 1;
END IF;

INSERT INTO `_db_log`(`log`) VALUES('id don`t isset ');
RETURN 0;
```

Выдает ошибку

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'log' cannot be null

А как он может быть `NULL`, если там стоит условие *IF @CACHEID*?

Comment: А если поменять условие с `IF @CACHEID THEN` на `IF @CHACHEID IS NOT NULL THEN` ошибка останется или все будет работать нормально?

Comment: @ApInvent, спасибо, заработало...

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментария:*

Значение `NULL` не эквивалентно 0. Если переменная `@CHACHEID` принимает значение `NULL` и условие `IF` не должно срабатывать, следует прибегнуть к специальному оператору `IS NOT NULL`, который вернет 1, если переменная не равна `NULL` и 0 в противном случае.

```
SELECT `id`, `val` INTO @CACHEID, @OLDVAL FROM `shop_ch_cache`
WHERE `prodid` = PRODID AND `nameid` = NAMEID LIMIT 1;

IF @CACHEID IS NOT NULL THEN
INSERT INTO `_db_log`(`log`) VALUES(CONCAT('id isset ', @CACHEID));
RETURN 1;
END IF;

INSERT INTO `_db_log`(`log`) VALUES('id don`t isset ');
RETURN 0;
```